# Create subsets of $[0, 1]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I would like to create a sequence of subsets $(D_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}}$ of $[0 ,1]$ in the following way:

$D_{1} = \{0, 1\}$,
$D_{2} = \{0, \frac{1}{2}, 1\}$,
$D_{3} = \{0, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, 1\}$, etc.

I tried to write it in the following way (knowing that each set will have $2^{k - 1} + 1$ elements):

$D_{1} = \{0, 1\}$ and for every $k > 1$,
$$D_{k} = \{x \in [0,1] \ | \ \exists p \in \{1, ..., 2^{k - 1}\}, x = \frac{p}{2^{k - 1}} \wedge \text{p does not divide $2^{k - 1}$}\} \ \cup \ D_{k - 1}$$

Is it correct ? If it is, do you have a "better" way to write it ? If it is not, can you help me to write it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $$D_k=[0,1]\cap 2^{-k}\Bbb Z=\{\,x\in[0,1]\mid 2^kx\in\Bbb Z\,\}$$?

Comment: Yes, that's better like that, thank you ! Was it correct in the way I wrote it ?